# How to call calculator in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to create calculator in windows phone 8.

I need api or DLL to call it from windows phone 8.

Is it available calculator for WP8?

Any reference or idea should help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with the Windows Phone 8 SDK: for launching apps/services, you need to use Launchers but in the launchers list, there isn't the calculator.
On Windows Phone 8 where you have access to more launchers via URI schemes, there is no way to launch the calculator. 
It seems like you will need to create your own calculator. Like an exciting one shown here:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Speech_Enabled_Calculator_For_Windows_Phone_8